# Terraform Azure network security

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-virtual-network, network-security-groups, terraform-provider-azure

I'm trying to configure a network security rule for a network security group in Azure via Terraform with multiple source addresses.

Based on the documentation
https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/network_security_rule.html

However, I'm not able to get this to work nor can I find any examples for it:

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/network_security_rule.html#source_address_prefixes

I get the Error:

Error: azurerm_network_security_rule.test0: "source_address_prefix": required field is not set
Error: azurerm_network_security_rule.test0: : invalid or unknown key: source_address_prefixes

Here is my sample:

```
resource "azurerm_network_security_rule" "test0" {
name = "RDP"
priority = 100
direction = "Inbound"
access = "Allow"
protocol = "TCP"
source_port_range = "*"
destination_port_range = "3389"
source_address_prefixes = "{200.160.200.30,200.160.200.60}"
destination_address_prefix = "VirtualNetwork"
network_security_group_name= "${azurerm_network_security_group.test.name}"
resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.test.name}"
}
```

Please let me know.

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, do you solve it? Can I help you more?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`source_address_prefixes` needs  list of source address prefixes.

Modify it as below:

```
source_address_prefixes = ["200.160.200.30","200.160.200.60"]
```

There also a mistake in `azurerm_network_security_group.test.name`, the correct type is `azurerm_network_security_group.test0.name`. The following tf file works for me.

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "test0" {
  name     = "shuinsg"
  location = "West US"
}

resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "test0" {
  name                = "shuinsgtest"
  location            = "${azurerm_resource_group.test0.location}"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.test0.name}"
}


resource "azurerm_network_security_rule" "test0" {
name = "RDP"
priority = 100
direction = "Inbound"
access = "Allow"
protocol = "TCP"
source_port_range = "*"
destination_port_range = "3389"
source_address_prefixes = ["200.160.200.30","200.160.200.60"]
destination_address_prefix = "VirtualNetwork"
network_security_group_name= "${azurerm_network_security_group.test0.name}"
resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.test0.name}"
}
```

Here is my test result.

[image]

Comment: When you ask an Azure question, you had better add tag `azure`, you will get the answer more quickly.

Comment: Thanks @shengbao-shui-msft.

I tried the exact same code you had pasted above and it fails with the exact same errors still.

{Error: azurerm_network_security_rule.test0: "source_address_prefix": required field is not set

Error: azurerm_network_security_rule.test0: : invalid or unknown key: source_address_prefixes}

Comment: what version of Terraform are you using?  I'm running    version v0.11.2 
installed via Chocolatey.

Comment: I use `v0.11.3`. I am sure the tf file works for me.

Comment: I suggest you could use the latest terrform. Also, what is your `provider "azurerm"` ?

Comment: I upload my [nsg.tf to Github](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Walter-Shui/ef77796f0e3b19330ac14c121de45570/raw/26e997d5d70ec0435b9d2bed701b46624a7739ce/nsg.tf), maybe you could check it. I also post my test result.

Comment: provider "Azurerm"  v1.0.1, I will try the latest as you have v1.1.0

Comment: @Shengboa Success:  After updating the Azurerm Provider version, that fixed the issue! Thanks for all your help!

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is the syntax when using PowerShell, not Terraform (although Terraform does support JSON syntax, which this is, but maybe not for this property).

Answer (score 1):

An "address_prefix" is a string values representing a CIDR e.g. `10.0.0.0/24`. So in your case `source_address_prefix = "200.160.200.30/32"` and `destination_address_prefix = "${azurerm_virtual_network.test.address_space.0}"` depending on what you want to refer to.

Comment: Thanks @GiulioVian <br/>
However, I received the following error: <br/>
"Error: azurerm_network_security_group.test: security_rule.2.source_address_prefix must be a single value, not a list"

Comment: I haven't checked the exact syntax (some resources want a list, some a single value): edit the answer

Comment: Also tried source_address_prefixes:

Error: azurerm_network_security_group.test: security_rule.2: invalid or unknown key: source_address_prefixes

Comment: @Parvez The root reason `source_address_prefixes` needs a list type. `""` this is a string type. See my answer.